# Should I sign open source code myself?

Tags: open-source, code-signing

I use macOS 10.14 and came across a problem when I tried to install an open source plugin for Vim that I found on Github. I downloaded the source code and compiled it myself, which worked well, but when I ran it, the execution was interrupted because the "Code signature [of executable] not valid for use in process".

This has given me a lot of questions that I can't wrap my head around:

I could either sign it myself, but wouldn't that kind of ruin the purpose of code signing? Is there any qualitative difference in signing code from the internet and allowing apps from unidentified developers in the "This app was downloaded from the internet" dialog box?

If I don't do it, whose "responsibility" is it to sign? The repository maintainer? The contributors? Is Apple expecting open source developers to always have an Apple Developer ID? Or have I misunderstood the purpose of code signing?

**Edit:**

To clearify, my question is how I should handle unsigned source code that I compile myself, since I don't expect contributers to always be able to, or remember to, sign their code, especially when it comes to tiny contributions to open source projects with many contributers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Ad-Hoc Code Signing

For third party applications and binaries that you compile yourself, and that *require* code signing, use an **ad hoc code signature**.

- I am assuming the application will not run without a signature;
- I am assuming the application will not be distributed;
- I am assuming you do not care about the identity of the signature being valid.

An ad-hoc signature does not provide reliable security benefits. It can be used to determine if the application has been changed and it can be used to apply security restrictions, such as entitlements, to an application.

An ad-hoc signature will validate against [`codesign`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/codesign/) but not [`spctl`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/8/spctl/). This may or may not matter depending on the binary being signed. For applications and executables, this is unlikely to matter because `spctl` is not run on locally created binaries.

#### Why Code Sign?

Regarding the refined question:

> How I should handle unsigned source code that I compile myself, since I don't expect contributers to always be able to, or remember to, sign their code, especially when it comes to tiny contributions to open source projects with many contributers.

**For most self compiled applications, there is no need for code signing.** This assumes you trust the application's code. On macOS, you can open untrusted applications from the Finder, see Apple's [Open an app from an unidentified developer](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH25088).

If you do not trust the code or the developers, do not compile or run the application.

### Your Responsibility

The provider of the source code has no responsibility or obligation to provide pre-built code signed binaries. Being self compiled, all code signing is your choice and responsibility.

- Apple *require* submissions to their App Stores to be code signed.
- Apple *request* developers outside their App Stores sign their code, but it is not yet required.

In both cases, only the final binaries are signed. The original source code and resources are not signed.

### Source Code is Not Signed

Source code itself can not be code signed in a meaningful way for macOS. Source files and code can be digitally signed, as any other file can be, but this makes no impact on how the resulting application or binary is treated by macOS.

### How to Ad-Hoc Code Sign a Mac Application

To codesign an application on macOS with an ad-hoc signature, set the identity `-s` flag to `-`:

```
codesign --force -s - </path/to/application>
```

All the other rules, requirements, and permutations of the [`codesign`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/codesign/) command remain the same.

The flag `--force` is used here to overwrite any existing signature.

You might need to add the `--deep` flag to the `codesign` command to sign sub-resources such as frameworks and embedded services.

Comment: Why do you recommend ad hoc signatures? The answer you linked to states "In practice creating ad-hoc signed binaries is only of practical value for Apple developers".

Comment: That doesn’t make any sense to me. Adding an ad-hoc signature means that signature validation will fail. This gets you nowhere at all - the program will fail with the exact same error message.

Comment: Yes, I see that you removed the link to my answer on ad-hoc signinig, and added the assumptions. But do these assumptions hold at all? - You seem to be answering as if the question is about running an application. It is not. It is about having an already signed application that the OP wants to add a plugin to. I.e. the plugin needs to pass library validation with the originally signed application (Vim) as the master.

Comment: The original question has been edited. It is rather broad as is. The questioner can comment, clarify, and try these answers to see what works for them. This answer attempts to answer the edited question and provide a practical approach. If it does not help, or has incorrect assumptions, the questioner can hopefully chime in and clarify their intent.

Comment: This answer was helpful. My question was quite general because I found the apple docs to be a bit hard to understand. Using ad-hoc signing solved the specific issue I had.

Comment: Great to hear ad-hoc signing worked for you.

Answer (score 6):

Signing the program yourself isn't ruining the purpose of code signing. The general purpose of code signing is to make it possible to verify that the program is an unmodified copy that was originally created by a specific entity (person or company). When you sign a program yourself only to run on your computer, you make it possible for the system to check that it is indeed you that created the binary, and that it hasn't been modified by others.

The qualitative difference between signing the application binary yourself, and just allowing apps from unidentified developers in GateKeeper is that in the former case you allow a single, specific app to run - whereas the latter, you open for the possibility that you can open lots of different apps just by right-clicking on them and choosing Open. I.e. it is more restrictive and thus somewhat more "secure" by signing the specific program yourself.

The responsibility of signing is entirely yours. The open source developer cannot sign the source code - it is only possible to sign the compiled binaries. As you're producing the compiled binaries yourself, it falls upon you to sign them.

You can sign up for a developer account on Apple's web site that will allow you to create a certificate that can be used for signing. If you're a developer and regularly compiling binaries to run on Macs this is the preferred way of doing things. If this is a one-off thing that you probably won't ever do again, it is probably overkill to go through this process. YMMV.

Other answers for your question here recommends that you use ad-hoc signing for your binary. That will not work. You will need to generate a valid signature in order to have the binary run with GateKeeper on its most secure setting.

Answer (score 0):

> Should I sign open source code myself?

If you're not the developer, then no.

[Code signing,](https://developer.apple.com/support/code-signing/) in a nutshell, is a method to say you (the developer) are who you say you are and the code hasn't changed since you last signed it.

> Is there any qualitative difference in signing code from the internet
>   and allowing apps from unidentified developers in the "This app was
>   downloaded from the internet" dialog box?

It sounds like your confusing Code Signing (what's required by Developers to publish Apps on the App Store) and [Gatekeeper](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202491) (what protects your Mac from installing software from unidentified developers).

If you allow your Mac to install software from both the App Store and identified developers, you will still get the popup alerting you to the fact software will be installed

[image]

And if it's from an unidentified developer, you will get the same popup with a "warning icon"

[image]

You can still install the software.  This is just a mechanism that forces user interaction to actually install the software providing you a layer of security against self-installed malware.

Comment: Thank you, this answers some but not all the questions. I have edited my question to try to be more specific in what I'm asking

Comment: Downvoted because it actually does make sense to adhoc sign an app as explained in @jksoegaard's answer. And if the developer did not sign it, why shouldn't the user do it to make Gatekeeper exceptions work?